# Set InDesign PDF export resolution for vector graphics

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector-graphics, pdf

I have an InDesign print document with several Illustrator `.ai` vector files. When I export the PDF, I believe the vector graphics are being rasterized at lower than 200 DPI. (I'm receiving a warning that an image is under 200 DPI from a service I upload the PDF to. They didn't say which, but I have narrowed it down to the vector graphics.) I have looked through the PDF export options and see nothing that mentions vector graphics. Where can I set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector graphics are resolution independent. Basically they are a series of math coordinates. That math is calculated upon output. PDFs generated from Indesign export the *math* not *raster images*.

Chances are it's the "service" which has the issue, not any vector elements within your PDFs, unless you are specifically setting InDesign to rasterize *everything* upon PDF export.

Comment: I believe it is being rasterized. If I open it in Photoshop and browse the individual images, I see chunks of the graphics that were vectors. Opening these results in a low resolution bitmap graphic. I should mention that I am using the `PDF/X-1a:2001` standard with `Acrobat 4 (PDF 1.3)` compatibility. If the option to rasterize everything includes text, it's not selected because text exports as text. Otherwise, where can I find the option to rasterize everything as you mentioned?

Comment: Photoshop **automatically** rasterizes everything if you open a non-Photoshop PDF.

Comment: The original Illustrator file may contain raster-based  effects, which I believe are not touched by InDesign.  So I'd first check that the file's raster effect resolution is set to 200 or 300dpi. (When you start an illustration as an RGB/Web/Screen-type document in Illustrator, it's set to 72dpi by default.) Open the illustration in Illustrator and check: `Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings…`

Comment: Also, there is a preflight feature in InDesign that lets you check the document against selectable pre-press requirements. Go `Window > Output > Preflight` and click the corner drop-down menu to define a new Preflight Profile. In the list of selectable test criteria, expand `IMAGES AND OBJECTS` and, under  `Image Resolution`, checkmark and/or type in the minimum  value required (250 or 300dpi). Problematic images will then be listed in the panel. See InDesign Help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-7060a.html